# Insert values to struct members through pointer of type struct

Tags: c

i don't understand a thing between pointers and structures; Why if i try to access struct members through pointer of type struct, and give them values using the pointer, i get segmentation fault ??

if i declare a struct pointer as:

```
typedef struct a {
int b;
}A;

int main(){
A *ptr;
}
```

I'm able to access the struct member using this syntax

```
(*ptr).b or ptr->b
```

Even if ptr points to nothing, ptr can access struct member because ptr is declared as type struct, right ??

If i don't explicitly set the pointer points somewhere, the pointer generally points  to his type, in this case A no ??

But when i try to give some values to the struct member through the pointer, i always got segmentation fault

```
ptr->b=9;
```

Comment: Accessing elements via an invalid pointer is syntactically correct, so it passes compilation. It causes undefined behaviour at runtime though. The behaviour is as expected.

Comment: If you don't point the pointer at something it is undefined behavior.  Not surprising it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

> Even if ptr points to nothing, ptr can access struct member because ptr is declared as type struct, right?

Why would it? A pointer just points to somewhere; that *somewhere* doesn't necessarily have to be a valid place in memory.

```
char* p = (char*)0x12345678; // Syntactically valid; not a real place in memory!
```

Pointers do not allocate any memory other than `sizeof(void*)` bytes to hold the actual address.

Since `ptr` is just a pointer, and not an *actual struct object* then there is no `A` struct allocated anywhere, hence the segfault.

```
A someA;
A* ptr;
(*ptr).b = 9; // or...
ptr->b = 9;
```

The above would be the correct usage.

Comment: But for example, if i declare a pointer like: int *ptr, it should point at an int no ?

Answer (score 0):

You told the compiler - please create this on stack `A *ptr;` so it did - but you did not allocate any memory (from the heap) or assign it to some variable

```
   --------------> Points to where ??
| ^ |
 /
ptr
```

Then you try to dereference it like this `*ptr` - you did not initialize it - so it has a right to take you to anywhere possible - hence its called Undefined Behavior.
Where should your compiler take you to?

You should have done:

```
A *ptr = malloc(sizeof(A));
```

or

```
A a1;
A *ptr = &a1; 


   ------------------> Points to   |  |
| ^ |                            a1/
 /
ptr
```

Answer (score 0):

the Variable ptr can be used to access struct members, if ptr does not point to a struct of the right type bad stuff may happen (the technical term for this bad stuff is Undefined behavior). Usually it's one of program terminates with an error, the program does the wrong thing, or program seems to do the right thing, less common results include "Anonymous" shuts down your business by exploiting your error..

If the pointer is not set to point somewhere, it (usually) points somewhere else, (it always points somewhere), types do not have a location that can be pointed to, the type is a property of the pointer, not a property of where it points, you must point it the right place if you want to use it.

segmentation fault is a common example of undefined behaviour.